# Chrome extension api add parameter to current url

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension

I'm just working on a 'simple' extension to add a parameter to the end of the current url. I've managed to get the current url, but can't perform a redirect to refresh the page with the added parameter. Code I have is as follows:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Something",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Woohoo",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },

    "background": {
      "persistent": false,
      "scripts": ["bgscript.js"]
    },

    "permissions": [
      "tabs"
    ]
}
```

**bgscript.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { 
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
        var currentUrl = tabs[0].url;

        chrome.extension.sendRequest({redirect: currentUrl + "?customparam=1"});
    });
});
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to perform a redirect like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The active tab at the time of clicking the browser-action is passed as an argument to the `onClicked` listener callback.

Furthermore, as mentioned in your comment, a little care is needed to append the custom query-parameter in the proper location and prepend it with the proper symbol. Specifically, the custom parameter should be placed **before** the hash (if any) and after the pathname (if any), but if there are more query parameters present it should be prepended with `&` instead of `?`.

```
var customParam = encodeURI('customparam=1');
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  var url = tab.url;
  var hashStart = (url.indexOf('#') === -1) ? url.length : url.indexOf('#');
  var querySymbol = (url.indexOf('?') === -1) ? '?' : '&';
  var newUrl = url.substring(0, hashStart) + querySymbol + customParam +
               url.substring(hashStart);

  chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: newUrl});
});
```

Comment: Damn. Now you're just showing off! I started to write something that would do this, but the result wouldn't have been as pretty!

Comment: Always glad to sho...ehm...to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, got it:

**bgscript.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { 
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
        var currentUrl = tabs[0].url;
        var newUrl = currentUrl + "?customparam=1"
        chrome.tabs.update({url:newUrl});
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need the `chrome.tabs.query(...)` at all, since the active tab is already passed to you (`tab`). So, all you need to place inside the listener callback is: `chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: tab.url + '?customparam=1'});`

Comment: @ExpertSystem - That makes more sense and simplifies it a bit (and I'm quite a simple person!), thanks again :). Just need to work out how to add it to a url with an existing parameter now - think that should be fairly straightforward though :)